# React JS - Function within Component cannot see State

Tags: reactjs

In code below the onclick function **testNewBug** is unable to access the state of its parent component 'BugList'. Can anyone see where I have gone wrong with this, I am correctly setting the state and can view it in DevTools, surely with the function within the component 'this.state'  should be working?

```
class BugList extends React.Component {

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      bugs: bugData
    }
  }

  render() {
    console.log("Rendering bug list, num items:", this.state.bugs.length);
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Bug Tracker</h1>
        <BugTable bugs={this.state.bugs} />
        <button onClick={this.testNewBug}>Add Bug</button>
      </div>
    )
  }

  testNewBug() {
      var nextId = this.state.bugs.length + 1;
      this.addBug({id: nextId, priority: 'P2', status:'New', owner:'Pieta', title:'Warning on console'})
  }

  addBug(bug) {
      console.log("Adding bug:", bug);
      // We're advised not to modify the state, it's immutable. So, make a copy.
      var bugsModified = this.state.bugs.slice();
      bugsModified.push(bug);
      this.setState({bugs: bugsModified});
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Oh dear I was being and idiot, I forgot to bind my event handler to 'this'

```
<button onClick={this.testNewBug.bind(this)}>Add Bug</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you know the method will always bind to the current class instance you can always define your method like this with `=>`:

```
testNewBug = () => {
      var nextId = this.state.bugs.length + 1;
      this.addBug({id: nextId, priority: 'P2', status:'New', owner:'Pieta', title:'Warning on console'})
  }
```

you won't have to worry about `bind(this)` all over the place and this assures the function has one instance per class.